# Are the Sons of the Harpy all dead?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Did the Dothraki kill them all in the Battle of the Bastards, or did any of them ditch their masks and go into hiding?

Comment: Closing this based on our "[Future-works policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5187/21267)". You will find out in future season(s).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question in accordance with our future works policy.

Comment: That wasn’t the Battle of the Bastards.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite- The events I mentioned took place in the episode *titled* Battle of the Bastards.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way we - or the characters in the show - could know for certain at the end of Season 6. They're secretive, and no-one knows their numbers, so no-one will know if they were all fighting at the gates (at least, no-one who'll tell).

---

That said, it stands to reason that **they're very *unlikely* to be all dead or defeated**. They're an insurgency from within the city, and the fighting that we saw happened outside the city gates. Their fighters and agents have tended to operate within the city, in the backstreets and shadows where they're most effective (and foreign Dothraki are least effective). It doesn't make much military sense to all leave a walled city to then attack it from a weaker position on the outside.

They slunk into the shadows and plotted the first time a battle of Mereen was lost; so it stands to reason that they'd do the same the second time.

If Daario's smart (an open question), he'll *expect* them to return. But neither he nor we know  for sure until the next season.

Comment: Dany evens tell Daario he must stay behind to keep the peace. This would imply she at least *thinks* there is potential for the another insurgency. If not the SotH, another group or city.

Comment: Daario is extremely smart, that's mainly "street-smart", which is what he'd need here.

Comment: Excellent answer, but to be honest, I doubt we'll ever hear much from Essos anymore.